# How can I use two functions with same click event in angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two function call addShop() and saveShop(). But I have only one button. It means only one click event. as an example

```
(click)=something();
```

So I need to put a fire those addShop and saveShop function in this same click event in two different times. kind of an if else I need to use for this.

Comment: ```(click)="confirmDelete() ; confirmDelete()"```

Comment: `(click) = 'confirmDelete(); confirmDelete()'`

Comment: @fatemefazli I edited the question. Now you can understand

Comment: @Sujay I edited the question. Now you can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(click)="variable==true ? addShop() : saveShop()"
```

we can pass true and false to the variable in two different times. Then if it is true fire addShop(), if it is false fire saveShop().

Answer (score -1):

```js
function confirmDelete() {
//do stuff of this functions
//delete process

//execute other fucntion here
otherFunction()
}

function otherFunction() {
//some other funcitons
}
```

```html
          <div class="btn btn-danger" id="confirmForDelete" (click)="confirmDelete()" translate>Confirm</div>
```